# Limitar append a un número n de iteraciones para operar con listas fuera y dentro de una clase

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un código que tiene una estructura similar a la siguiente, en pseudocódigo. En el ejemplo en pseudocódigo se ha escrito `class Uno` y `def main()` para dar una idea de la estructura general del código real que utilizo e intentar transmitir la idea de que habrá asignación de valores de dentro a afuera de la clase y viceversa. He decidido esta aproximación intentando plantear un ejemplo mínimo que sea a la vez mínimamente coherente para el propósito de la pregunta.

```
from numpy import mean
x = []
nueva_x = [1,1]
class Uno: 
    mi_lista=[[1,1],[1,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,0],[1,0]]
    for i in mi_lista:
         x.append(i)
    print(nueva_x)
def main():
    variable_1 = [1,2,3]
```

Es decir, declaro inicialmente una variable `x` que es una lista vacía y una variable `nueva_x`, que es una lista que contiene inicialmente una serie de valores. La lista `x` va adjuntando sucesivamente las listas que hay dentro de `mi_lista`.

Lo que busco es:

1. que la lista `x` vaya adjuntando las listas de `mi_lista` por el mismo número de iteraciones que elementos tiene `variable_1` (en el ejemplo 3).
2. una vez se hayan adjuntado en `x` un número de listas igual a `len(variable_1)`, y sólo entonces, calcular la media de los valores de las listas adjuntas en `x` y asignarlo a `nueva_x`. En el ejemplo, una vez `x` ha adjuntado 3 listas `x=[[1,1],[1,1],[0,1]]`, calculamos la media así `media_x=mean(x, 0)`.

El objetivo es que cuando corra el código real, el `nueva_x` dentro de la clase  tome el valor inicial hasta que se cumplan las "n" primeras iteraciones (en el ejemplo 3). Desde entonces `nueva_x` tomará su nuevo valor, y así hasta que se cumpla nuevamente el criterio del paso 1. Y así sucesivamente.

Mis intentos hasta ahor han pasado por farragosas funciones. Pero estoy seguro que tiene que existir una manera sencilla de limitar el número de listas que se adjuntan con alguna función similar a `append`. Una vez, hecho esto, me gustaría saber cómo proceder con el tema de la sustitución y asignación del nuevo valor a `new_x`, así como cómo formatear la lista `x`.

Gracias por los comentarios de antemano.

**Actualización con un código real (6/11/2019)**

A continuación vemos un ejemplo con un código más aproximado al código real. Se trata de un ejemplo mínimo del código real (abajo comparto el código).

**Contexto:**

Como puede observarse al ejecutarse el simulador, el juego (`juego.jugar`) itera a lo largo de `ronda` en los `emparejamientos`. De este modo, cuando la ejecución llega al punto clave `def choose`, se imprime el `self.sigma` correspondiente al `jugador` (tomado de `self.nombre`) que está siendo simulado en ese momento. Como puede observarse `self.sigma` es una lista con valores de 0 a 1.

**Objetivo**

Se desea crear una variable `i` que vaya adjuntando las listas self.sigma de cada "jugador" por el mismo número de iteraciones que `jugadores` tenemos. En el caso presente, 4.

Una vez se haya adjuntado en `i` un número de listas igual a `len(jugadores)`, y sólo entonces, calcular la media de los valores de las listas adjuntas en i y asignarlo a `nueva_i`. En el ejemplo, una vez `i` ha adjuntado 4 listas `i=[[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1]]`, calculamos la media así `media_i=mean(i, 0)`.

Dado que la media de `i` en cada ronda, es decir `nueva_i`, pretende ser utilizada en el futuro para hacer una serie de cálculos a lo largo de la simulación dentro de `def choose`, esta lista `nueva_i` debe tener asignado un valor previo a cada ronda (su valor iniciar será el de las medias de las sigmas iniciales asignadas en `main()`). A su vez, en una futura versión del código, dentro de `def_choose`, esta `nueva_i` interferirá en cada ronda con el `self.sigma` de cada jugador, modificándolo. En resumen, se necesita que `nueva_i` recoja la media de `self.sigmas` de la ronda anterior. Cada jugador tendrá su  `self.sigma` propio, pero `nueva_i` será común a todos los jugadores en cada ronda. Todas estas cosas concatenadas explican mi intento inicial de trabajar con una variable global `i` que pase a `nueva_i` la media de las `self.sigma` de los jugadores y luego se formatee de ronda en ronda.

```
from __future__ import division
from random import random
from bisect import bisect
from collections import deque, Counter

i=[]
nueva_i=[]    

def choice(opciones, probs):
    probAcumuladas = list()
    aux = 0
    for p in probs:
        aux += p
        probAcumuladas.append(aux)
    r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
    op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
    return opciones[op]

class Jugador:
    def __init__(self, nombre, senales, sigma, b, x, m, menLen):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.senales = senales
        self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.__mem_mostradas = deque(maxlen=menLen)
        self.__men_observadas = deque(maxlen=menLen)
        self.sigma = sigma[:]  
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m

    def memoriza(self, mostrada, observada):
        self.__mem_mostradas.append(mostrada)
        self.__men_observadas.append(observada)
        mostradas = Counter(self.__mem_mostradas)
        observadas = Counter(self.__men_observadas)
        self.mem_mostradas = { signal: mostradas.get(signal, 0) for signal in self.senales }
        self.mem_observadas = { signal: observadas.get(signal, 0) for signal in self.senales }

    def __str__(self):
        return "Jugador_{}".format(self.nombre)

    def with_b(self, muestra, observa, r, idx):
        if not (muestra == observa == 0):
            result = (
                ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r)
                + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa / r)
                + ((0.98) * self.b * self.sigma[idx])
                + ((self.m / 8))
            )
        else:
            result = (
                ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r)
                + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa / r)
                + ((0.98) * 0 * self.sigma[idx])
                + ((self.m / 8))
            )
        return result

    def choose(self, r):
        probs = [
            self.with_b(
                self.mem_mostradas[op], self.men_observadas[op], r, indx
            )
            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)
        ]
        elecc = choice(self.senales, probs)

        #Aquí es donde se necesitará llamar a self.sigma y nueva_i
        print(self.sigma)
        print(nueva_i)

        return elecc

class Partida:
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, sigmas, b, x, m, menLen):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.jugadores = {
            nombre: Jugador(nombre, senales, sigmas[nombre], b, x, m, menLen)
            for nombre in jugadores
        }
        self.memoria = list()
        self.entropy = float()

    def generar_senales(self):
        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores, self.senales))
        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = {}
            for jugador in self.jugadores.values():
                eleccs[jugador.nombre] = jugador.choose(r)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs

    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
        for ronda in self.emparejamientos:
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)
            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].memoriza(observada=senales[jugador2], mostrada=senales[jugador1])
                self.jugadores[jugador2].memoriza(observada=senales[jugador1], mostrada=senales[jugador2])

def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"]
    emparejamientos = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(1, 3), (2, 4)], [(1, 4), (2, 3)]]

    patron = 1

    menLen=3

    s1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
    s2 = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    sigmas = {1: s1, 2: s1, 3: s2, 4: s2}

    muestras = [{"b": 0.0, "x": 0.5, "m": 0.02}]

    muestras = [d for d in muestras for _ in range(1)]

    simulaciones = 1

    for sim in range(simulaciones):
        for mu in range(len(muestras)):
            juego = Partida(
                jugadores,
                emparejamientos,
                senales,
                sigmas,
                muestras[mu]["b"],
                muestras[mu]["x"],
                muestras[mu]["m"],
                menLen
            )
            juego.jugar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Tengo varias dudas sobre tu descripción. 1) Los valores en `variable_1`¿no se usan para nada? ¿sólo su número de elementos? 2) La media que quieres calcular ¿sería la media de `x`? porque has puesto `data` en su lugar... 3) Si es la media de `x`, ya que `x` es una lista de listas ¿qué entiendes por su media? ¿Una lista con las medias de cada lista, es decir, en tu ejemplo sería  [1, 1, 0.5]? ¿O la media de todo esto, que sería 1.16666?4) En `nueva_x` se deben ir añadiendo las medias, o cada iteración "sobreescribe" las anteriores? (en ese caso ¿qué sentido tiene?

Comment: En definitiva, creo que ayudaría a comprender mejor lo que buscas si pones en cada paso qué valores tendrían tus listas. O cuando menos qué valor final esperas al terminar todas las iteraciones. Tal como lo has explicado, parece que sólo guardarías el resultado de la última iteración, si cada una "resetea" lo hecho en la anterior

Comment: En mi opinión la pregunta es demasiado amplia ya que pide mucho para una sola pregunta: Parece que quiere que hagamos todo su trabajo ¿Qué piensan los demas?

Comment: He acotado la pregunta. También he reducido el número de objetivos para evitar cualquier malinterpretación. Gracias por el comentario @abufalia. En efecto la media es de 'x' (o 'i' en el nuevo ejemplo), utilizando 'numpy'. El código creo que te será familiar porque me echaste una mano en el pasado con una versión aprecida :)

Comment: @eyllanesc No me parece que sea el caso que dices. Sólo es que (inicialmente) intentó evitar plantear su problema real, e intentó traducirlo a uno más simplificado, con el resultado de que no se entendía bien, la pregunta era muy amplia, y daba la sensación de no haber intentado nada. Tras la edición me queda claro que no es así, aunque sigue siendo complicado entender bien qué se pide.

Comment: @abulafia como tu señalas en el momento que escribi el comentario la pregunta era demasiado amplia donde parecia a la típica pregunta: *quiero 1, quiero 2 y quiero 3 ¿Alguien me da el código?*, obviamente con la edición ya no es el caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## El problema

Creo que en el fondo se trata de un problema XY, es decir, el usuario tiene una necesidad X, pero pregunta por otra cosa Y (pues al intentar resolver X le apareció el problema Y). Este tipo de cuestiones suelen llevar mucho tiempo, y mucho trasiego de mensajes hasta finalmente aclarar cuál era X y cuál Y. Tras varios comentarios, reediciones de la pregunta, etc. he llegado a la siguiente conclusión

El problema X que el usuario originalmente tenía sería:

> Para cada ronda del juego, quiero calcular el promedio de unas listas almacenadas en los objetos-jugador, de modo que estos objetos puedan usar luego esa información en la ronda siguiente.

Pero al ir a implementar esta idea, el usuario se encontró con problemas de visibilidad de variables. La lista de jugadores está en un lugar. La información de los "sigma" (que son los valores cuyo promedio quiere calcular) están en otro lugar, dentro de cada jugador. Y la función en la que pretendía implementar el promedio estaría aún en otro lugar (una función global) con lo que no sabía cómo acceder a los datos de los jugadores, etc. Además, ya que los jugadores después necesitaban acceder al resultado de ese promedio, decidió hacer ese promedio una variable global.

Ante este escenario, no supo como proseguir, y planteó la pregunta Y que vendría a ser:

> Cómo acceder a listas dentro y fuera de una clase a la vez que se limita el número de iteraciones basándose en los contenidos de otra lista.

Este problema Y es mucho más difícil de comprender y de resolver, y por eso la pregunta estuvo tiempo sin recibir la atención.

Pero ahora que el problema X está claro, pasemos a su solución.

## Solución

El uso de variables globales se desaconseja. Toda información que una función necesite se le debe pasar como parámetro. Si estamos usando programación orientada a objetos, podemos simplificar un poco ya que en ese caso las funciones son métodos del objeto y pueden acceder (vía `self`) a atributos del objeto que vendrían a ser como variables globales, pero específicas de ese objeto.

Usando esta idea propongo:

- Que el cálculo de `nuevas_i`, la lista con los promedios, se haga desde un método de la clase `Partida`, pues esta clase tiene en uno de sus atributos la lista de jugadores, lo que le permitirá iterar por esa lista y acceder a los sigma de cada jugador, sin mayor problema.
- Que el valor de `nuevas_i` resultante se guarde como un atributo de la clase `Partida`, ya que esta lista es útil para todos los jugadores (de algún modo la compartirán todos).
- Que la función `choose` que necesita esa lista, la reciba como parámetro. En este caso no puede tomarla del objeto `Partida`, porque la función `choose` es de cada jugador.

Con estas ideas las modificaciones al código serían:

- Eliminar las variables globales `i` y `nueva_i` (y poner un `import numpy as np` para el posterior cálculo del promedio)
- Modificar `choose()` para que reciba un parámetro adicional: `nueva_i`
- Modificar el constructor `Partida.__init__()` para que inicialice `self.nueva_i` con el promedio de las sigmas iniciales:

  ```
      self.nueva_i = np.mean(list(sigmas.values()), 0)
  ```
- Modificar la llamada a `choose()` para pasarle `self.nueva_i`, en el método  `Partida.generar_senales()`. Las líneas en cuestión quedarían así:

  ```
          for jugador in self.jugadores.values():
              eleccs[jugador.nombre] = jugador.choose(r, self.nueva_i)
  ```
- Modificar el método `Partida.jugar()` para que sea al final de cada ronda cuando se actualice `self.nueva_i` con el promedio en cuestión. La nueva versión de este método queda así:

  ```
  def jugar(self):
      gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
      for ronda in self.emparejamientos:
          senales = next(gen_sens)
          self.memoria.append(senales)
          for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
              self.jugadores[jugador1].memoriza(observada=senales[jugador2], mostrada=senales[jugador1])
              self.jugadores[jugador2].memoriza(observada=senales[jugador1], mostrada=senales[jugador2])
          # Calcular la media de las sigmas de la ronda anterior
          i = [ jugador.sigma for jugador in self.jugadores.values() ]
          self.nueva_i = np.mean(i, 0)
  ```

¡Y creo que esto es todo! Quedo a la espera de comentarios adicionales para ver si había comprendido bien el problema X (el problema Y casi que ya renuncio :-))

Comment: En efecto, mi enfoque inicial ha sido hacer las  variables `i` y `nueva_i` globales, para luego poder acceder a ellas desde `def_choose`. Dado que  `i` y `nueva_i`  pretenden ser las mismas para cada jugador en cada ronda,  `Partida` podría se un buen lugar para implementarlo. He conseguido algo parecido mediante la implementación de i y nueva_i globales, aunque parece que esta no es la manera más conveniente de proceder.

Comment: Por otro lado, la interpretación parece correcta, por ahora. He añadido más información en la pregunta inicial para intentar saisfacer dudas. Muchas gracias @abufalia

Comment: Para que termine de enterarme y pueda proponer una solución. Cada jugador tiene un `choose()` desde el cual se necesita usar `nueva_i` (pero no `i`, verdad?) Entiendo que lo más simple sería pasarle esa lista como parámetro a `choose()`. Por otro lado, ¿dónde se construiría `nueva_i`? Yo propuse en un método de la clase Partida, pero ¿qué método sería? ¿desde dónde es llamado?

Comment: En efecto, cada jugador tiene un `choose()` desde el cual se necesita usar `nueva_i`, pero no `i`. La lista `i` la ideé como una lista global meramente instrumental para obetener `nueva_i`, pero no se operará con ella (no interferirá en la simulación). Por otro lado, yo había pensado construir `nueva_i`de manera global. Sin embargo, es muy posible esto no sea aconsejable. Quizá sea mejor hacerlo dentro de `Partida`. He añadido un comentario en el código justo en el lugar donde se pretende utilizar tanto sel.sigma como nueva_i.

Comment: @abufalia Muchas gracias por la solución, que como es habitual, es excelente y denota una capacidad extraordinaria para comprender los problemas planteados y darles una respuesta didáctica. En efecto, esta solución es mucho más elegante y eficaz que la de la variable global que sugería. Necesito hacer un par de comprobaciones más mañana para ver si todo responde a lo que exactamente busco en el simulado. Entre tanto, si consideras que el título de la pregunta puede ser editado para recoger mejor el tema tratado, soy todo oídos.